# LEFT JOIN tables and null values that dont exist in the right

Tags: mysql, sql-server, left-join

I have two tables, `Customers` and `customerTowns`. I would like to store the town name in `customerTowns` and link to it from `townID` stored in `Customers`

`|Customers|
 |townID   |`

`|customerTowns|
 |townID       |
 |townName     |`

And my sql is as followed,

```
SELECT townName, Customers.townID
FROM customerTowns
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers
ON Customers.townID = customerTowns.townID
```

This nearly returns the result im looking for. Except, I would like the `townID` to be repeated for each entry in `customerTowns`.

`|townName  |townID|
 |London    |1     |
 |London    |1     |
 |London    |1     |
 |London    |1     |
 |London    |1     |
 |Manchester|NULL  |
 |Liverpool |NULL  |`

I feel I must be close, just cant figure out how to return just one row, or why its returning multiple rows!

My desired output would be;

`|townName  |townID|
 |London    |1     |
 |Manchester|NULL  |
 |Liverpool |NULL  |`

Comment: you could use select distinct   -- this will eliminate duplicate rows

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(townName, Customers.townID)
FROM customerTowns
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers
ON Customers.townID = customerTowns.townID

Comment: When townID is null it is because there was not a row in Customers that matched.

Comment: thanks @cristian, I have tried `SELECT DISTINCT` and its returning 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'. Will have a read. Have also updated my question with the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a group by or distinct.

```
SELECT townName, Customers.townID
FROM customerTowns
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers
ON Customers.townID = customerTowns.townID
GROUP BY townName, Customers.townID;

SELECT DISTINCT townName, Customers.townID
FROM customerTowns
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers
ON Customers.townID = customerTowns.townID;
```

Comment: Many thanks popovitsj! Thats great! would there be any advantage of one over the other?

Comment: The advantage of grouping is that you can also add aggregate functions like count(), max() etc. Other than that, I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most efficient way to do this is using `exists`:

```
SELECT ct.townName, 
       (exists (select 1 from Customers c where c.townID = ct.townId))
FROM customerTowns ct;
```

The reason your original query is returning duplicates is because it returns one row for each customer.  Because your join is on `TownId` in both tables, you really just need to see if a customer exists for that town.  This should perform better than a query that requires a `distinct` or `group by`.

Comment: thanks for exaplining Gordon, really apprecaitre you taking the time. Will try this out today at some point